# Filter array with multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Let's imagine that I have an array of emails and I want to filter a specific domain, like:

```
const emails = ['test@hotmail.com', 'test@gmail.com', 'test@yahoo.com']
const excludedDomain = '@hotmail';
// This works fine
const eligibleEmails = emails.filter(email => !emails.includes(excludedDomain));
console.log(eligibleEmails);
```

I tried to work with [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#examples), but it returns a boolean and I need to return a new filtered array. Tried to mix `filter()` and `some()` but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another filter on excludeDomain inside your original filter.

```
const emails = ['test@hotmail.com', 'test@gmail.com', 'test@yahoo.com'];
const excludedDomains = ['@hotmail', '@yahoo'];

const filtered = emails.filter(email => 
  excludedDomains.filter(ed => email.includes(ed)).length === 0
)

console.log(filtered); // [ 'test@gmail.com' ]
```

Comment: Hey could you please ```email.includes(ed)).length === 0``` explain what does this line means in words if possible?

Comment: `.filter` returns an array. If there are any elements in the array, then that means one or morre of `excludedDomains` is/are present in `emails` array. Is there are elements in the array filtered inside, that means the current email addres needs to be excluded. Therefore we check if the length of inner filtered array is 0, if so, we retain that email address else we drop it.. (comparison always yeilds to either true or false, which is what filter expects

Comment: @Nikkkshit (sorry forgot to tag you)

Answer (score 1):

Combine [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if any of the `excludedDomains` `includes()` in the current email we're filtering

```js
const emails = ['test@hotmail.com', 'test@gmail.com', 'test@yahoo.com']
const excludedDomains = ['@hotmail', '@yahoo'];

const eligibleEmails = emails.filter(e => !excludedDomains.some(ee => e.includes(ee)));
console.log(eligibleEmails);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet filters the emails by excludedDomains to return your eligible emails.

```js
const emails = ['test@hotmail.com', 'test@gmail.com', 'test@yahoo.com'],
  excludedDomain = ['@hotmail', '@yahoo'],
  eligibleEmails = emails.filter(email => excludedDomain.some(str => email.indexOf(str) > -1));

console.log(eligibleEmails);
```